# What is the added benefit of the vendor provided FTDI USB to Serial driver?

Tags: macos, usb, driver

Future Technology Devices International Ltd. provides a driver for their USB-to-Serial chips specific for MacOS 10.9 and above.

When I first connect a device with such a chip, I can see the additional devices in /dev, for example tty.usbserial-A92XHN3R and cu.usbserial-A92XHN3R. Apparently, MacOS (10.12.6 in my case) provides a driver out of the box.

After installing the vendor provided driver (and rebooting), nothing changes on first sight. I still see the two additional devices when I connect an FTDI adapter to a USB port.

But there is at least one change: libusb works with a PN532 breakout board connected to the Mac via an FTDI adapter. Before installing the driver, I got an error, even though the adapter seemed to work fine.

After this long preamble comes the question: What exactly are the benefits of the vendor provided driver? Does it have additional functionality over the Apple provided driver? Less bugs?

Comment: Are there release notes or a link on what the “vendor provided driver” is specifically? I have no idea what you are using and what version of that other driver you wish to compare and contrast. You’ll likely get no answer or less good answer without nailing down what you are using.

Comment: My apologies, I found an installation guide http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_134_FTDI_Drivers_Installation_Guide_for_MAC_OSX.pdf. It claims in chapter 3.2 that "Starting with 10.11 (El Capitan), Apple’s own driver seems to be sufficiently comprehensive that many customers will not need to install FTDI’s own VCP unless they wish to use its advanced features such as baud-rate aliasing and configurable latency times."

Comment: Why libusb works with the driver installed (but not active, as I did not disable the apple driver first) is an entirely different question. This question would be even more "opinion-based" or speculative, so I am not going to ask it.

Comment: Perfect. I’ve reopened this for an answer to be added.

Comment: would you like me to answer with the baud rate information from your comment?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment! Yes, this might help shedding some light to the mystery. Do you know libusb? Does it use one of the advanced features that are mentioned in the installation guide? From the outside it looks like libusb uses a simple serial connection, and yet it doesn't work with the Apple provided driver.

Comment: @Martin Something seems to be off with the information you have given. The FTDI and macOS drivers communicate via USB with the device to give you a serial port. Libusb is used so that user-space programs can communicate with a USB device without using a driver (such as the FTDI and macOS built-in drivers). Therefore something seems to be missing from your explanation as you wouldn't be needing both. Perhaps you're not talking about libusb, but rather libnfc?